# find all numbers next to a certain keyword

Tags: bash, text-parsing

I have a text file. It contains some texts. the text is mixed of strings and numbers. I'd like to find all numbers that occur next to a keyword.
For example (keyword here is `day`):

> Today is really nice **32** day. Tomorrow I will eat 3 pizzas with 10 of my friends next time we will take **50** day or **19** day

(sentence is pure nonsense for anyone wondering).
I'd like to extract numbers **32**, **50** and **19**.

Im a newbie in bash so far I can read the content from the file and extract all numbers

```
echo $(grep -Eo '[0-9\]+' $i)
```

edit2:
keyword MUST be day. daylight, daynight are not allowed. sorry for misunderstading

Comment: `echo $()` is redundant 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` supports PCRE (`-P`) e.g with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po '\d+(?=\s+day\b)'
```

- `-`o just gets the matched portion
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- The zero-width positive lookahead, `(?=\s+day\b)`, matches one or more whitespaces, followed by string `day`, then word boundary

**Example:**

```
% grep -Po '\d+(?=\s+day\b)' <<<"Today is really nice 32 day. Tomorrow I will eat 3 pizzas with 10 of my friends next time we will take 50 day or 19 day"
32
50
19
```

Answer (score 1):

In GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='[ \n]' '{if(p~/[0-9]+/&&/^day/)print p;p=$0}' file
32
50
19
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option that works without GNU's grep extensions:

```
grep -o '[0-9][0-9]* day\>' | awk '{print $1}'
```

But if you want to use perl regexes (which is what GNU `grep -P` does), you can always just, you know, use perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 while /(\d+) day\b/g' foo.txt
```

Comment: I do not know if you coped my answer or not but I got **downvote**. and **mklement0** comment me Why I copied your answer. I answered before you, and you know that already.

Comment: Uhm, my answer is an hour older than yours. it's right there in the timestamp.

Comment: I have no concerns about down-vote since mine is wrong for missing `\b` **thank you for mentioning that** but copying someone else answer is ridiculous and I have never tied ever

Comment: nobody accused you of copying, either; they just pointed out that your answer was a near-duplicate of mine. You're the only one who mentioned copying answers. :)

Answer (score -1):

For a pure bash solution here's one:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read -r -a arr; do
    for (( i = 0; i < $(( ${#arr[@]} - 1 )); i += 1 )); do
        word=${arr[i]}
        next_word=${arr[$(( i + 1 ))]}
        [[ $word =~ ^[-0-9]+$ ]] &&
        [[ $next_word == "day" || $next_word == "day"[[:punct:]] ]] && 
        echo "$word"
    done
done < "/your/input/file" #or "$1" or whatever
```

Which reads the file line by line, creating an array of each line.
The array is then iterated over by it's length - 1 and each item is checked if it's a number, and then if the next word is the word `day` with either some or no punctuation.

An easy optimization of skipping the known lines is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Please generally don't post pure Bash solutions that process lines in a loop unless you preface such answers by saying that such an approach will be much, much slower than using suitable external utilities such as `grep` or `awk`.
In this specific case, the solution not only performs poorly, but is significantly more complex and cumbersome than the `grep` and `awk` solutions. If your intent is to show Bash features, state that too.

Comment: Case in point: Let's create a file with 1000 repetitions of the sample line: `{ for i in {1..1000}; do echo 'Today is really nice 32 day. Tomorrow I will eat 3 pizzas with 10 of my friends next time we will take 50 day or 19 day'; done } > file`
With your code, processing takes about 1.5 secs. on my machine. Using `grep -Po '\d+(?=\s+day\b)'` (heemayl's solution), it takes about 0.03 secs - a factor of 50.
The execution times and ratio will vary based on many factors, but the point is: for all but _small_ files, a looping Bash solution is the wrong approach.

Comment: The question wasn't tagged as `grep` or `awk` but `bash`, thus I provided a `bash` solution. Performance wasn't in the question either.

Comment: You can infer from the OP's own solution attempt - which involves `grep` - that the intent is _not_ to have a pure Bash solution. In the vast majority of cases, people use the `bash` tag to mean: "I want a solution that I can use from a `bash` (shell) script / on the command line, using standard utilities."

Comment: And providing a working solution in your mind is a bad thing then? I see now what people mean when they say that this community is really toxic.

Comment: If you read my comments, you'll see that my complaint is not about your solution _not working_ (it does). I've tried to explain to you why I think your solution isn't helpful _in its current form_ and what it would take to make it more helpful in my eyes. When we didn't reach a shared understanding and the answer remained as-is, I down-voted. I see nothing toxic in this - this is how the community is intended to work. I always _prefer_ reaching a shared understanding (and ideally learn from the dialog), but that doesn't always happen.

Comment: @OlliK  Although the answer provides the correct output it is less than optimal. I think maybe the point being made was that by not disclosing the performance impact of this solution compared to the others, that people may stumble upon this post and with limited knowledge of bash+utils may see this as the best way to do it, which as explained by mklement0, it is not.